# What is the recommended maximum number of time steps for RNN or LSTM?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

More time steps incurs longer training time, which above certain limit becomes impractical. What is the recommended maximum limit of the number of time steps for RNN or LSTM? I'm using a powerful workstation with GPU, but not a server. Around a few hundreds time steps? A few thousands time steps?

Comment: This has zero context. What is your dataset?

Comment: as a very rough rule of thumb, RNNs struggle to learn dependencies more than 50 timesteps long. LSTMs struggle with more than maybe 500.